# a prime is a midpoint of two primes

Tags: prime-gaps

Take three consecutive primes $p_1,p_2,p_3$:

What is the opinion on the question that 
$p_3-p_2=p_2-p_1$ occurs endlessly and is harder to find as the primes increase?

Has anyone examined the frequency of these cases as the primes increase?

Comment: Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primes_in_arithmetic_progression

Comment: And in particular https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_prime

Comment: If one has six consecutive primes p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6 then a triangle with co-ordinates at (p1,p4), (p2,p5), and (p3,p6) will have the same area an infinite number of times.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A122535